# R Shiny write log to ui on each step

Tags: r, shiny

In my R Shiny app I want to write a log to the UI on each step to see the progress. My current code is something like below. `output$msg` is a `verbatimTextOutput` control.

```
msg<-"Started\n"
output$msg <- renderText({ msg })

msg<-paste(msg,"Get data\n")
output$msg  <- renderText({msg})
```

The problem is the `msg` is seen in the page only after the whole code is executed. I want the `msg` to appear the same time it gets executed.

The code execution takes some time so it helps to see the progress.